# AWS GlueStudio 'datediff'

Tags: amazon-web-services, pyspark, aws-glue

Has anyone tried using AWS GlueStudio and the custOm SQL queries? I am currently trying to find the difference in days between to dates like so..

```sql
select
datediff(currentDate, expire_date) as days_since_expire
```

But in the data preview window I get an

> *AnalysisException: cannot resolve '`currentDate`' given input columns: []; line 3 pos 9; 'Project ['datediff('nz_eventdate, 'install_date) AS days_since_install#613] +- OneRowRelation*

Does anyone know how to fix this solution or what causes it?

Answer (score 1):

You don't write PostgreSQL/T/PL (or any other flavor) SQL, instead "you enter the Apache SparkSQL query". Read the following carefully:
Using a SQL query to transform data (in AWS Glue "SQL Query" transform task)
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/ug/transforms-sql.html

The functions you can write in AWS Glue "SQL Query" transform task to achieve desired transformation are here (follow correct syntax):
https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-ref-functions-builtin.html

BTW: The error you wrote is not correlating with your select statement for many potential reasons, but I am writing this answer anyway just for the sake of your question heading or other who may come here.